# WIX/MSI - Is it possible to make a package which leaves files that existed prior to installation when you uninstall

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, uninstallation

I am using WIX to create MSI's which install standard files (no exe, com's, DLL's etc). On some users computers some of the files in the MSI may already exist. During the install this is not a problem as MSI automatically updates files that are older etc. However, during uninstall I hit my problem.

It is easiest to explain with an example:
Joe Bloggs has "file B" on their computer. This file has not been installed by an MSI package and is not being track by the Microsoft Installer system in anyway. It is just a normal file on the computer.

Joe Bloggs downloads and installs my package which contains "file A", "file B" and "file C". When he installs my package the Microsoft Installer system checks "file B" and establishes it is identical to the "file B" in my package. It therefore does not replace "file B" but it does mark the MSI component that file B is part of as installed.

Joe Bloggs then decides he does not like my software so uninstalls my package. When he does this all 3 files are removed despite "file B" existing before my package was installed. My investigations have established that this is because the component that contains "file B" is marked as installed. Therefore when you uninstall the package it removes "file B".

This is all a bit technical but hopefully there is a WIX / MSi expert out there that knows a solution.

Thanks

Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done through backup and restore custom actions.

Basically, you write a custom action which can copy some files based on the parameters it receives. You can then use this custom action twice in your installer:

- once during install to copy the original file in a backup folder (usually temp or application data)
- once during uninstall to copy the backup file back in the original location

Comment: Have you get any info on how this can be achieved. I have done quite a lot of googling but can't seem to find examples of custom actions that will do this. Maybe I am using the wrong search terms.

Comment: It's done through custom code (C++, VBScript, C# etc). You can use anything you want (EXE, DLL, VBS etc). Here is a VBScript example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytxss84h(VS.85).aspx . The paths can be passed through installer properties or through a command line.

Comment: Is it possible to call the custom action in such a way that all files paths that are part of the installer are passed to my VBS / EXE etc. In other words pass the MSI file table (if that is the right table name) to the custom action. The custom VBS / EXE will the iterate through the files backing up those that exist on install or restoring those that do not on uninstall. If that is not possible would you just call the custom action for each file?

Comment: Yes, you can read the file table through a DLL custom action. This is done through the Windows Installer API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368250(VS.85).aspx . You can find a sample C++ DLL custom action here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If the files may already exist on the machine mark `Component/@SharedDllRefCount="yes"`

Windows installer will then automatically update the reference count if it finds the files already existing.

Comment: Does this work even if the file that already exists on the machine has not come from another MSI package. In other words the sharedDLLRefCount that is incremented does NOT exist prior to my package [link](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_component.htm)

Comment: yes - MSI just looks at the registry and creates\increments the ref count for the file at that location.

Comment: But not if the file was just copied there manually. There won't be any ref count, so the MSI install will add just 1, instead of 2 which is what Jium wants.

Comment: @George I thought so. By incrementing the ref count to 1 it would mean that when I uninstall the MSI it would still remove the files as the ref count would be reduced to 0 and thus file removal would occur. It seems that the only way is to wait until the ref count exists and add another 1 to it or to backup existing files and restore them after uninstall completes. I think the ref count hack is better as no backup files have to be stored. Can you give any info on how I achieve the ref count hack. Failing that info. on backing up files. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known "problem" when using MSI and is generally caused by a **bad deployment strategy**. The lacking reference counting is actually merely a symptom of an error-prone deployment approach.

**In almost no case should your installer interfere with files that exist, or are likely to exist, before your installation is run. This includes files you have installed yourself that are reference counted by another of your own installers! Think cohesion & coupling, only one installer should deal with each file.**

This general rule normally triggers a response along the lines of "our case is special". Trust me, it isn't. An application should use its own installation folder under Program Files, its own folder under user settings, and its own folder in shared settings. It should **never** replace or update shared files such as user dictionaries, exclusion lists or similar.

Often such an approach is to facilitate a "developer cruch" where config files need default values for the app to function. Completely unacceptable. The application itself can access shared files, even update them if it has access, but it can **not** replace the whole file with "default settings" or uninstall the whole file on uninstall. **It is an application responsibility to create a running environment in the absence of basic configuration files.** The files should then be generated from the applications internal defaults or be copied from read-only default files placed elsewhere.

If you share config files between different installers I would deploy them with a merge module, or simply set the component(s) that contain(s) the file(s) to "**shared**" and "**permanent**" and "**never replace if already exists**". Doing so should be the "easy fix" to the symptom you describe, even if you don't follow the deployment advice I recommend above.

Comment: What would be your solution to this: We wish to develop a deployment system for both authors and users of free addons for a game. This game has lots of different addon developers, some free and some payware. We have no control over the way developers deploy there files. Our addons extended or adds new functionality. The only way to do this is to deploy files that often already exist. At the moment deployment is a low tech zip and a readme about what files to edit, copy, move etc. Very slow and prone to user error. We can do everything we want using WIX/MSI except handle uninstall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know would be to hack the registry. If you increment the

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLS\<your dll name>` value after MSI has finished creating it, during uninstall MSI will see that the file is still in use and not remove it. This is pretty hacky, but it would work.

Or you could back the files up to another location, and on uninstall, copy them back.

Comment: No, don't touch this registry key. You can auto-increment it using Component/@SharedDllRefCount="yes" as explained by saschabeaumont above.

Comment: Yes, but as I describe above(3 years ago btw, so things may have changed) if that key doesn't exist and you add your @SharedDllRefCount="yes", it will increment the counter by 1, instead of by 2, which is what the original post asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to add a better answer than the one I wrote before. It seems I may not have read the question properly. I will try to break this down to a few options:

1. It is possible to install files with Windows Installer that are then not tracked by reference counting at all.  In other words they are never uninstalled. You do this by **blanking out the component GUID containing the file**.
2. However, in my opinion files that are not tracked by MSI like this are really data files, and should not be dealt with in the normal way. Rather you can install them read-only to a shared location - for example Program Files - and then you can have your application copy them to each user's own data folder. They are then unreferenced by MSI and nothing will ever touch them. A longer discussion of this topic can be found here: http://forum.installsite.net/index.php?showtopic=21552
3. **saschabeaumont**'s Component/@SharedDllRefCount="yes" approach should also work (I haven't tested). What this setting does is to increment the legacy style SharedDll ref-counter in the registry (*HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs*). As such it is a non-MSI reference feature and I wouldn't rely too much on it personally. MSI reference counting is done in a much more intricate way in *HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer* and *HKCR\Installer* among other places. **Don't touch anything here directly!**

A good **rule of thumb** with an MSI component, is that once you define a key path (absolute path in the registry or on disk) for a component, Windows Installer thinks it "owns the key path" and will reference count it. If the ref-count is 1 it deletes the key path and anything else that was in the component on uninstall.